# Bazel and BuildGrid TLS

Tags: ssl, grpc, tls1.2, bazel

I'm trying to run a BuildGrid Server and connect a BuildGrid Bot to it, and then run a Bazel build.

I can get this to work with TLS disabled, but I want TLS on.

The issue is that I can't seem to work out how BuildGrid and Bazel are supposed to communicate with TLS...

BuildGrid docs give these commands to generate TLS:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -batch -subj "/CN=localhost" -out server.crt -keyout server.key
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -batch -subj "/CN=client" -out client.crt -keyout client.key
```

BuildGrid Server has these options:

```
tls-server-key: /path/to/server-key
tls-server-cert: /path/to/server-cert
tls-client-certs: /path/to/client-certs
```

With this I can get BuildGrid Server and BuildGrid Bot talking, so I know I'm pretty close.

Bazel has these options:

```
--tls_certificate=<a string> default: see description
Specify a path to a TLS certificate that is trusted to sign server certificates.

--tls_client_certificate=<a string> default: see description
Specify the TLS client certificate to use; you also need to provide a client key to enable client authentication.

--tls_client_key=<a string> default: see description
Specify the TLS client key to use; you also need to provide a client certificate to enable client authentication.
```

So I ran Bazel with:

```
--tls_client_key=client.key --tls_client_certificate=client.crt
```

But Bazel fails to start with the error:

```
Failed to init TLS infrastructure using 'client.crt' as client certificate: File does not contain valid private key: 'client.key'
```

If I use this script from Bazel to generate the TLS Self-Signed Certificate: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/test/testdata/test_tls_certificate/README.md

I get various SSL errors depending on which files I feed into the BuildGrid Server settings.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to test a configuration like so:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/certs && cd /tmp/certs/
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -batch -subj "/CN=localhost" -out server.crt -keyout server.key
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 3650 -nodes -batch -subj "/CN=client" -out client.crt -keyout client.key
```

Use this in your buildgrid conf file:

```
server:
  - !channel
    address: localhost:50052
    insecure-mode: false
    credentials:
      tls-client-certs: /tmp/certs/client.crt
      tls-server-cert: /tmp/certs/server.crt
      tls-server-key: /tmp/certs/server.key
...
```

Then you can start the server with: `bgd server start config.yml`

In your bots setup, you can specify these certs as well:

```
$ bgd bot \
  --instance-name=main \
  --remote https://localhost:50052 \
  --client-key /tmp/certs/client.key \
  --client-cert /tmp/certs/client.crt \
  --server-cert /tmp/certs/server.crt \
  --remote-cas https://localhost:50052 \
  --cas-client-key /tmp/certs/client.key \
  --cas-client-cert /tmp/certs/client.crt \
  --cas-server-cert /tmp/certs/server.crt \
  host-tools
```

And then when running bazel you can specify the following arguments:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples
$ cd examples/cpp-tutorial/stage1
$ bazel build \
    --tls_client_key  /tmp/certs/client.key \
    --tls_client_certificate /tmp/certs/client.crt \
    --tls_certificate /tmp/certs/server.crt \
    --spawn_strategy=remote \
    --remote_executor=grpcs://localhost:50052 \
    --remote_instance_name=main \
    //main:hello-world
```

Note: make sure to use `grpcs://` as the protocol and not `grpc`. Hope this helps!